# Why does my iPhone App continue in the background?

Tags: iphone, ios

I wrote my first iPhone App, and managed to get it into the App store. I later discovered a bug that happens on a real device but not on my emulator. I have committed a fix (changed plist to prevent app running in background), but I don't really understand why it happened.

My App allows users to record a sound-byte, however while they are recording they can use the iPhone home button to move the app to the background, and then it can keep recording forever if they don't restart the phone or the app does not crash.

My impression from everything I have read, is that this should not happen as you have to ask for background audio specifically if you want to do this, but now it appears to me that you have to ask specifically to disable it.

Could anyone explain this to me?

Comment: what's your problem recording in background or not allowing app in background?

Comment: My problem is I don't understand why it records in the background when I didn't ask for permission to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS App lifecycle is described in Apple's [iOS App Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW35).

The App is given the opportunity to save data and otherwise stop things that don't need to be running, before being suspended.  You can request extra time doing this by using  [beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler%3a).

If you want your app to stop doing its "normal thing" when it is put into the background then you need to detect the App state transition and stop it yourself.

Comment: So I can record audio as long as I want in the background, but play audio is a special case which you need to add permissions for?

Comment: You will only be given about 5 secs to clean-up before being suspended.  If you want to play audio however, you can set the `UIBackgroundModes` key to `audio` in your `Info.plist` file and become a long-running background task.